# Having a null foreign key in torque 4

Tags: java, sql, torque

Is there a way to get torque to translate a value of 0 to null, for a foreign key?

I have the following schema:

```
<table name="juser" idMethod="native">
 <column name="id" primaryKey="true" required="true" type="INTEGER"/>
 <column name="name" required="true" size="2147483647" type="VARCHAR"/>
</table>

<table name="juserDepend" idMethod="native">
 <column name="id" primaryKey="true" required="true" type="INTEGER"/>
 <column name="juserRef" required="false" type="INTEGER"/>
 <foreign-key foreignTable="juser">
  <reference foreign="id" local="juserRef"/>
 </foreign-key>
</table>
```

And my table is created with this sql:

```
create table juserDepend(id serial not null primary key,
 juserRef int,
 name text not null,
 foreign key(juserRef) references juser(id) on delete cascade
);
```

As can be seen, in JuserDepend there is an optional foreign key(juserRef) to the juser table, but I can't seem to get torque to understand that. Right now I have no way to save a juserDepend object with a null value in juserRef, because torque uses the integer value 0 which the database then complain about because it's not a valid foreign key.

My preferred solution would be that torque simple translated 0 to null, for all foreign keys where null is a allowed value. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer mind, I found the answer. I just added
javaType="object" to my foreign key, and then I can set it to null.